# Notational confusion on derivative of multivaribale functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

These problems are from the book "Calculus on Manifolds" by M. Spivak. I have some notational confusions on these problems.

[image]
[image]

$\textbf{Solutions:}$

[image]
[image]

$\textbf{Q1:}$  I know that, $Df(a)$ denots the derivative of $f$ at the point $a$. For a function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $Df(x)$ is is a function of $x$ and $Df(a)$ is a constant. For $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$, $Df(x)$ is a matrix of order $m\times n$ with variable entries $x$ (that is $Df(x)$ is a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$.). So at a particular point $a$, $Df(a)$ should be a matrix with constant entries. Then what does it mean in Problem(2) that $Df(a)=f$ ?

$\textbf{Q2:}$ In Problem(4), $Ds(a,b)$ denotes the derivative of $s$ at the point $(a,b)$, that should be also a constant. Butwhat does it mean that $Ds(a,b)=s$ ?

$\textbf{Q3:}$ In Problem(5), what is the meaning of the notation $Dp(a,b)(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Given a function $f \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, and a point $a \in \Bbb R^n$, the derivative of $f$ at $a$ is a linear transformation $Df(a) \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$. So, $Df(a)$ is itself a function; and for $x \in \Bbb R^n$, the value of $Df(a)$ at $x$ is written as $Df(a)(x)$, which is an element of $\Bbb R^m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $F:V\to W$ where $V,W$ are powers of $\Bbb R$, and $p\in 
V,$ $DF(p)$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$ (which may be represented by a matrix, but it is useless here).

In the particular case $V=W=\Bbb R,$ such a linear map is of the form $t\mapsto kt$ and may then be identified to the constant $k.$

In the other particular case where $F:V\to W$ is linear, the linear map $DF(p):V\to W$ is $F$ itself, i.e.$$\forall h\in V\quad DF(p)(h)=F(h).$$

Comment: $DF(p)$ is derivative at the point $p$ ?

Comment: You are probably unable to understand my question! I know derivative is a linear transformation.

Comment: 1/2 Yes, like you wrote in your post after "$\textbf{Q1:}$ I know that". 2/2 I am used to your question. My students often had the same.

Comment: Suppose for a certain function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, derivative $Df(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$. Then $Df(2,1)=(3,1)$. Right ?

Comment: Yes. $Df(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$ is linear transformation.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is a linear map. Then, $Df(x,y)=f(x,y)$. So $Df(1,2)=f(1,2)$ ?

Comment: @Empty No, $Df(x,y)$ is a linear transformation, whereas $f(x,y)$ is an element of $\Bbb R^2$ (or whatever the codomain of $f$ is). The equality $Df(x,y) = f(x,y)$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Empty you are confusing $DF(p)\in L(V,W)$ with $DF:V\to L(V,W).$ Look at the new version of my answer. Btw did *you* downvote it?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, if some of my comments goes rude. Still I am confused. $DF$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$. That is $DF\in L(V,W)$. Then what about the point $p$ ?

Comment: No. I didn't downvote it.

Comment: Yes, at the last line in answer, $DF(p)\in L(V,W)$. How can we read $DF(p)$? Derivative of $F$ at $p\in V$ ? Then what is the meaning of $DF(p)(h)$ ? That was my Q3.

Comment: Yes $DF(p)$ is the derivative of $F$ at the point $p. $ It is a linear map from $V$ to $W$ hence for any vector $h\in V,DF(p)(h)$ is an element of $W.$ That was azif00's comment to your post, 40 min ago.

Comment: Ok. So, derivative of $F$ at a point $p$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$. How can we relate this when $V=W=\Bbb R$ ? Suppose, $F:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $F(x)=x^2$. Then derivative of $F$ at a point $x=1 \in \Bbb R$ is $DF(1)=2$. So how can we say this is a linear transformation from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!